# Call a button in the method of a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button

Can you help referencing a button from the OnCreateView down to its method?

Here is my code.

```
public class static placeholder extends Fragment {

    public placeholder()
    { ... }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        Button pc = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPc);

        ...
    }

    //Call the button pc to this method
    public void callPc()
    {
        //Reference the button Here!
    }
}
```

I already try to call this using `getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPc)` but it does not work. I also used `getActivity()` but it does not work too.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/weightLimitResultBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is the return value of the `onCreateView`?

Comment: `return rootview` in `onCreateView`

Comment: Do you mean you want an onClickListener attached to a button in a fragment?

Comment: Override `onActivityCreated()` and `setOnClickListener()` inside?

Comment: _I already try to call this using getView().findViewById(R.id.btnPc) but it does not work. I also used getActivity() but it does not work too._  Can you tell how **how** it's not working? Is it throwing an error? Crashing?

Comment: Guyz.. thank you for all your comments and quick response to my post.

Comment: I got it now. .Thank you so much. getView is working but there is a problem when declaring into my code. @josephus thanks you.

Comment: @ROd_algonquin I forgot to add it there sorry but in my code I return it.

Answer (score 0):

add param to your button xml

```
android:onClick="callPc"
```

or you can initialize your button object global (after initialize class)
and then you can call your button anywhere

or you can set param to your callPc() like this

```
public void callPc(Button btn)
{
    btn.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. GOD BLESS YOU.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write code for onClicklistener in onViewCreated method  becouse you are using a fragment ....

```
 @Override  
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    pc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
          // your action for button click 


         }
         }); 
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for this Idea. Yeah, that's what I've done and the things I want to do is I want to call a button inside a method of the fragment. All in all i would like to say THANKS. GOD BLESS YOU..